# Sandcastle documentation xml code example displaying without carriage returns

Tags: xml, documentation, sandcastle

I'm using sandcastle to document at web service API and to summarys and remarks to the top level Namespace I've add a sandcastle.xml file to my project.

My problem is when I try and add a xml example code to the namespace remarks section 
in that xml file sandcastle renders the xml code all on one line without any of the carriage returns.

```
<member name="N:BrokerServices.GatewayAsmx">
    <summary>summary text</summary>
    <remarks>
        remarks text
        <example>
               Sample xml code              
               <code lang="xml">
                <Membership>
                    <firstname>Cliff</firstname>
                    <lastname>Mayson</lastname>
                    <age>27</age>
                </Membership>
            </code>
        </example>
    </remarks>
</member>
```

The resulted rendered code example displays as:

```
<Member><firstname>Cliff</firstname><lastname>Mayson</lastname><age>27</age></Member>
```

I've tried using \n or \r which work but the \n and \r characters are left in the code example:

```
<Member><firstname>Cliff</firstname>\n
    <lastname>Mayson</lastname>\n
    <age>27</age>\r
</Member>
```

How do I insert new lines without the new line characters show in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the code tag's language attribute is xml you need to add xml:space="preserve" attribute to the tag for the xml example to render correctly.

eg.

```
<member name="N:BrokerServices.GatewayAsmx">
    <summary>summary text</summary>
    <remarks>
        remarks text 
    </remarks>
    <example>
        Sample xml code             
        <code lang="xml" xml:space="preserve">
            <Membership>
                <firstname>Cliff</firstname>
                <lastname>Mayson</lastname>
                <age>27</age>
            </Membership>
        </code>
    </example>
</member>
```

This is not necessary if the code tag's lang attribute value is c# or VB

Comment: Cheers, It would seem you're right about the example being top-level tag too. Although it does seem to work when its nested in remarks.

Answer (score 3):

1st option: replace the `<` characters with `&lt;`.
2nd option: put your XML code into a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block.
3rd option: you can also use alternative tool like [ForgeDoc](http://www.forgedoc.com) :)

One more thing: don't put example blocks into the remarks section. `Example` is a top-level tag.